# Remove null rows in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, null, pyspark

When I loaded a fairly large dataset (i.e. Wikipedia's archives) into a spark dataframe, I received the below error:

```
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
```

What is the best way to remove Null values within a pyspark dataframe?

Comment: This is the function to remove empty row from dataframe in pyspark

**df = df.dropna(how='all')**

Answer (score 4):

you can use `na.drop()` in order to remove all rows including Null values:

```
df.na.drop()
```